# Kubernetes/Docker clustering with sharing of resource

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cluster-analysis

does Kubernetes have a function like VSAN in VMs where they share the same storage and an app will not be replicated but just be shared ?

Ex. when one node goes down, another node that shares the same resource should be running the same app.

Answer (score 0):

If a node goes down then all the pods/apps running on that node gets shifted to other available node(s) in the kubernetes cluster.

Comment: but do they share same storage?